# XAML How to set simple property value without binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Suppose I have some singleton class like this:

```
class A
{
    public static A Instance {
        get { return me; }
    }

    public Object SomeProperty
    {
        get { return something; }
    }
}
```

and another class like this:

```
class B
{
    public Object TheProperty
    {
        get { return tp; } 
        set { tp = value; }
    }
}
```

If I were using C# syntax, I would write something like:

```
b.TheProperty = A.Instance.SomeProperty
```

Unfortunately, I have to do this in XAML. **I know I could create a Dependency Property for class B**, also implement the PropertyChanged method of some sort, and after several hours of dull work have a monstrous "overkill" solution.
I hope that I am missing something, and there is an easy way to do it in xaml like:

```
<B TheProperty={??A.Instance.SomeProperty} />
```

Answer (score 1):

As i suspected. You need to use an object data provider.

```
<Window x:Class="DataPRoviderTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataPRoviderTest"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="provider" ObjectType="{x:Type local:B}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
            <x:StaticExtension MemberType="{x:Type local:A}" Member="Instance"/>
        </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TheProperty, Source={StaticResource provider}}"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

You also need a new constructor for `B` that takes an instance of `A`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DataPRoviderTest
{
    public class A
    {
        public static A Instance
        {
            get { return new A(); }
        }

        public Object SomeProperty
        {
            get { return "Hi there"; }
        }
    }

    public class B
    {
        public Object TheProperty
        {
            get { return tp; }
            set { tp = value; }
        } Object tp = null;

        public B(A instance)
        {
            TheProperty = instance.SomeProperty;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But doesn't that require my TheProperty to be a DependencyProperty?

Comment: @TimurNuriyasov Try my edit. I'm wondering if you will be forced to fall back upon `ObjectDataProvider`... Is there any reason you can't do this in code behind or a view model? Setting up non-dependencyobject object graphs is not XAML's strongest area.

Comment: It's not a question of whether I can do the dependency object or not. I just don't feel like it's a good enough solution. It annoys me that such a trivial thing requires so much effort.

Comment: SomeProperty needs to be static. It isn't in the question

Comment: I hope you see where I'm going - so much code for a simple A=B

Comment: @TimurNuriyasov it would take 1 line in c#. Use the appropriate tools.

Comment: @TimurNuriyasov if `SomeProperty` is a static property, can you update the question?

Comment: well, it may look like just one line of code, but that's changing the architecture. Something I definitely don't want to do. Like why would B take A as an instance? Just for the sake of neat XAML?

Comment: SomeProperty is NOT a static property.

Comment: @TimurNuriyasov well this solution should work well for you. The only change is a constructor overload.

Comment: You don't understand what the question is, how about if the `TextBlock.Text` is not a dependency property? You can't set a binding to a non-dependency property.

Comment: @JokeHuang thanks for ignoring the rest of the comments after 7 years ;)

Answer (score -2):

try use the path keyword like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PropertyName.SomeProperty}" />
```

and set the entire single instance to the PropertyName property of the instance which is binding

Comment: Yes I know this is what people usually do when they work with WPF. You write a nice little XAML, but your codebehind becomes something like `public Boolean State
  {
    get { return (Boolean)this.GetValue(StateProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(StateProperty, value); } 
  }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty StateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "State", typeof(Boolean), typeof(MyStateControl),new PropertyMetadata(false));` plus an additional piece of logic for handling PropertyChanged() events

Comment: I think you can do it with a simple property which raise PropertyChanged() in the singleton class. Then set the entire singleton instance to the property of the instance that the page is binding

Comment: I don't think this is answering the actual question. In this example the TEXT property is already a dependency property. That's what the OP is trying to avoid.